# if $\varphi$ assumes a maximum value, then it is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic defined on a domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$. Set

$$\varphi(z)=\vert f(z) \vert + \vert g(z) \vert.$$

If $\varphi$ attains its maximum value on $U$, then prove $f,g$ are constant functions.

So my idea is starting with the point $z_0 \in U$ such that

$$\bigg \vert \vert f(z) \vert + \vert g(z) \vert \bigg \vert \leq \bigg \vert \vert f(z_0) \vert + \vert g(z_0) \vert \bigg \vert \leq \vert f(z_0)\vert + \vert g(z_0) \vert, \space \text{for all $z \in U$}$$
but then I get stuck, is it possible for me to say since $\varphi$ is bounded, then by the maximum modulus principle then its constant? Or so I state $\varphi$ is constant since it is analytic and attains a max value? then argue that a constant which is the sum of two functions need be constant?

Comment: It should be some application of Modulus Maximum Principle

Comment: Thanks, what I thought!! @TitoEliatron

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1757995/42969

Comment: @MartinR the solutions there do not utilize maximum modulus principle which is what I am trying to use.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/429226/42969 (which uses the MMP).

Comment: @MartinR thanks!!!!